# Reload bx-slider in commonJS module

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bxslider, commonjs

I need to reload [**bxslider**](http://bxslider.com/options) in `commonJS` module.

This is example how to do it inside one file:

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
slider.reloadSlider();
```

But I have `slider init` function inside `commonJS` module:

```
var allsliders = {
    bx: function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }
};
module.exports = allsliders;
```

And I'm using it as `allsliders.bx()`

So how to use method `slider.reloadSlider();` from first example inside `commonJS` module?

I need `slider.reloadSlider();` method in some other modules, not here. So I can use it after some event.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work.

```
var allsliders = {
    bx: function () {
        slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        slider.reloadSlider();
    }
};
module.exports = allsliders;
```

Comment: I need `slider.reloadSlider();` method in some other modules, not here. So I can use it after some event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allsliders = {
    bx: function () {
      slider : function () {
         return $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
      },
      refreshSlider : function () {
        if(typeof allsliders.bx.slider !== 'undefined') {
           allslider.bx.slider.reloadSlider();
        }
      }

    }
};

module.exports = allsliders;

// to access the reload you have to call allsliders.bx.refreshSlider();
```